# get subclass constructor in super class

Tags: javascript

```
var Super = function() {}
Super.prototype.newOfThisKind = function() {
    return new this.myConstructor()
}
var Sub1 = function() { this.myConstructor = Sub1 }
var Sub2 = function() { this.myConstructor = Sub2 }
Sub1.prototype = new Super()
Sub2.prototype = new Super()
console.assert(new Sub1().newOfThisKind() instanceof Sub1)
console.assert(new Sub2().newOfThisKind() instanceof Sub2)
```

This code works as expected, but how can I write *newOfThisKind* without setting *myConstructor* in each subclass?

Comment: I don't think It may be done. But why you need that anyway?
If it's just to trigger some action, just create a second method.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. The goal is to use newOfThisKind on any Super instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i do not understand what is the goal, but to answer your question :

```
    var Super = function () { }
    Super.prototype.newOfThisKind = function () {
        return Object.create(this);
    }
    var Sub1 = function () { }
    var Sub2 = function () { }
    Sub1.prototype = new Super()
    Sub2.prototype = new Super()
    console.assert(new Sub1().newOfThisKind() instanceof Sub1)
    console.assert(new Sub2().newOfThisKind() instanceof Sub2)
```